# Dynamically adding columns for SQL PreparedStatement - still safe against injection?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I am trying to prevent SQL injection in my Java program.  I want to use PreparedStatements to do this, but I don't know the number of columns or their names in advance (the program allows administrators to add and remove columns from the tables). I'm new to this, so this may be a silly question, but I'm wondering if this approach is safe:

```
public static int executeInsert( String table, Vector<String> values)
{
    Connection con;
    try {
        con = connect();

        // Construct INSERT statement
        int numCols = values.size();
        String selectStatement = "INSERT INTO " + table + " VALUES  (?";
        for (int i=1; i<numCols; i++) {
            selectStatement += ", ?";
        }
        selectStatement += ")";     
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(selectStatement);

        // Set the parameters for the statement
        for (int j=0; j<numCols; j++) {
            prepStmt.setString(j, values.get(j));
        }

        System.out.println( "SQL: " + prepStmt) ;
        int result = prepStmt.executeUpdate();
        con.close() ;
        return( result) ;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println( "SQL EXCEPTION" ) ;
        System.err.println( "Inserting values " + values + " into " + table);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Basically I'm creating the String for the statement dynamically based on how many values are passed in (and therefore how many columns are in the table).  I feel like it's safe because the PreparedStatement is not actually created until after this string is made.  I may make similar functions that take in actual column names and incorporate them into the SQL statement, but these will be produced by my program and not based on user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you have values like `table` being inserted into your query without escaping, you should test against a whitelist of known-good values. This prevents people from being creative and causing trouble. A simple dictionary or array of valid entries usually suffices.

Using a prepared statement is a good idea, but be sure the statement you're preparing doesn't allow for injections right from the start.